# Does the sequence $x_n = n$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

Let $E = \{x \in\mathbb R : x \ge 1\}$. For all $x, y \in E$, we define
$d(x, y) = |1/x − 1/y|$ (the distance between two points in this sequence).

Does the sequence $x_n = n$ converge?

Comment: What do you mean converge, which term converge?

Comment: I mean does the sequence converge given that distance between two points in the sequence. 

My understanding is that convergence means it approaches a specific point. Correct?

Comment: @yaoliding Is the convergence of the sequence independent of the distance between the points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convergence in this case means the following: There exists $x\in E$ such that $d(x_n,x)\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Assume that there is such an $x\in E$. Then $x\geq 1$ and $d(x_n,x)\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. However, we have
\begin{align*}
d(x_n,x)=d(n,x)=\left|\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{x}\right|\to\frac{1}{x}>0
\end{align*}
as $n\to\infty$, a contradiction. Thus, $(x_n)$ does not converge.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. I had part of this but appeared to have blanked on the n approaching infinity portion.

Answer (score 0):

Just take a relabel of $E$ and $d$. Consider $E'=(0,1]$ and $d'(x,y)=|x-y|$.

The sequence in $E'$ here turns to be $x_n=\frac1n$. It's so called Cauchy sequence, but it does not converge. Because we can't find a limit point inside $E'$.

Comment: Never thought about it this way. I had proven it was Cauchy but got stuck on this portion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fix $x\in E$.  Put $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{x}$.  Then there is some $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $x<N$.  Then for all $n\geq N$, we have
$$\left|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{n}\right|=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{n}>\frac{1}{x}=\varepsilon.$$
Thus, each element of the subsequence $\{x_{n+N}\}$ is at least $\varepsilon$ distance from $x$, hence $\{x_n\}$ does not converge to $x$.  Since $x\in E$ was arbitrary, this shows that $\{x_n\}$ does not converge.